# Apply font to words containing in custom dictionary in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, dictionary

I'm wondering if I can apply a specific font to a custom dictionary in MS Word? That way, if I add a new word to that dictionary, the font will apply to it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar question over at StackOverflow, so I provided an answer there. It can be done with a VBA module. The downside is you have to relocate your custom dictionary, which means you'll have to make future modifications by hand (e.g., using Notepad).

Check out my detailed response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700316/ms-word-2003-vba-use-only-custom-dictionary-for-replacing-format-in-non-spel/13080624#13080624

Hope that helps!

**Edit**: I should note in case it isn't clear, you'll have to manually run the macro (using Alt+F8) and it will apply the custom formatting to all applicable words.

-- jm